# Use json path as string variable in jq

Tags: php, json, jq

I have a tiny example:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "b": "aaa",
    "c": ""
  },
  "d": "bbb"
}
```

And I trying to get the value from `a.b` and this json path is from string.

I am trying to do as:

```
$ echo '{"a": {"b": "aaa", "c": ""}, "d": "bbb"}'  | jq '"a.b" as $key | .[$key]'
null
```

I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the path string by the dots to get a path array, which you can use with `getpath`:

```bash
jq -r '"a.b" as $key | getpath($key / ".")'
```

```
aaa
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PbLp_HWRO1I)

Note that this works for object fields. If you want it to also work with array indices, you'd need to convert digits to numbers (using `tonumber`), and come up with a solution how to disambiguate field names that only consist of (stringified) numbers.