# jq: error: versions/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:

Tags: jq

This is my script that should compare 2 files but parameters bring from 3rd txt file

```
diff_output=$(diff <(jq ".$param" "$path_to_file1") <(jq ".$param" "$path_to_file2"))
```

in my txt file

```
.txt
args1,args2,def.args-pod,def.car
```

args1,args2,def.car are work but def.args-pod no and send answer

```
jq: error: pod/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

please help me change this
diff_output=$(diff <(jq ".$param" "$path_to_file1") <(jq ".$param" "$path_to_file2"))

my yaml

```
{
  "args1": "/my-api/",
  "def": {
    "args-pod": "^0.7.9",
    "car": "^0.8.8"},
   "args2": "^0.9.5",
}
```

Comment: Please include the declarations of `$param`, `$path_to_file1`, and `$path_to_file2`. It looks like they're coming from splitting the "txt file" at commas `,`, but you might want to split at comma and space `, ` as the `args1,args2` "column" already contains a comma by itself.

Comment: Please read  about [mcve] , AND the section [How to turn a bad script into a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash). Good luck.

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing the structure of your JSON file. For example, we don't know if you need to index into `{"def.car": ...}` or `{"def": {"car": ...}}`; and each requires a different technique.

Comment: Beyond that, using `diff` this way is a code smell. [In most cases `comm` is a more appropriate tool](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036), as the worst-case performance of the algorithm to calculate the smallest transformation between two files is far worse than the worst-case performance of a sort operation (and satisfying its prerequisite of sorted input is the only part of using comm that isn't O(n)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359009/use-json-path-as-string-variable-in-jq

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "$param" has the value "def.args-pod" won't work when interpolated into the invocation of jq.

`jq ".$param" "$file"` would become `jq '.def.args-pod' '/path/to/file'` which is obviously incorrect. For the program to be correct, this needs to be `."def.args-pod"` or `.["def.args-pod"]`.

But you shouldn't use string interpolation to build jq programs anyway, instead pass variables and use those:

```
jq --arg prop "$param" '.[$prop]' "$file"
```

This assumes your input JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "def.args-pod": "some value, array, or nested object"
}
```

If it doesn't, please edit your answer to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Further reading: [How to use jq when the variable has reserved characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018393/how-to-use-jq-when-the-variable-has-reserved-characters)

Comment: my json ```{
  "args1": "/my-api/",
  "def": {
    "args-pod": "^0.7.9",
    "car": "^0.8.8"},
   "args2": "^0.9.5",
}```

Comment: @user22667148 A very important detail. In that case, my answer will not work.

Comment: i resolved this for that code: ``` done < <(grep -o '^[^#]*' "$my-txt-file" | sed '/^\s*$/d')